# How to upload large pytorch model to azure?

Tags: azure, machine-learning, pytorch

I have locally pretrained pytorch (.pth) model that has ~500mb in size. I have created azure function which loads the model from azure static storage, but it takes over 5 minutes to load, which causes HTTP request to function to time out. How could I approach storing/loading model of this size?

Comment: hello brother, did you solved that problem, plus can you suggest some tutorial for me to deploy pretrained-yolov5 model on azure?